GridDB Not Connecting to Cluster: Getting 'Connection Refused' Error
I'm currently trying to set up a GridDB cluster for a project that involves processing time-series data. I followed the official documentation to set up the GridDB server and configure the cluster.
Here are the steps I followed:
Installed GridDB on a Linux server (Ubuntu 20.04).
Configured the gs_cluster.json and gs_node.json files according to the documentation.
Started the GridDB server using the gs_startnode command.
Attempted to connect to the GridDB cluster using the Java client API.
However, when I try to connect to the cluster using the following code:
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("notificationAddress", "239.0.0.1");
    props.setProperty("notificationPort", "31999");
    props.setProperty("clusterName", "myCluster");
    props.setProperty("user", "admin");
    props.setProperty("password", "admin");

    GridStoreFactory factory = GridStoreFactory.getInstance();
    GridStore store = factory.getGridStore(props);

I receive the following error:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refusedWhat
I've Tried:
Checked Firewall Settings: Ensured that the ports (31999 and 10001) are open and not blocked by any firewall.
Verified Network Configuration: Confirmed that the server is reachable from the client machine using ping and telnet.
Logs: Checked GridDB server logs (gsserver.log and gsnode.log) but didn't find any significant errors related to the connection.
Restarted GridDB: Tried restarting the GridDB server multiple times, but the issue persists.
Environment Details:
GridDB Version: 4.5
OS: Ubuntu 20.04
Java Version: OpenJDK 11
Questions:

What might be causing the "Connection refused" error when trying to connect to the GridDB cluster?

Are there any specific configurations or settings in gs_cluster.json or gs_node.json that I should double-check?

Is there a better way to debug this connection issue?


Any help would be greatly appreciated!
